# Contador en cursor devuelve un número más alto del que debería

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Resulta que tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Usando al menos 3 cursores anidados, mostrar para cada departamento los nombres de los proyectos que tienen y cuántos empleados trabajan en ese proyecto y como se llama el empleado que más hora trabaja en este proyecto.

Tengo la siguiente estructura de la base de datos empresa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es: usando al menos 3 anidamientos ─que eso ya lo tengo bien─, mostrar el nombre de los departamentos, luego el nombre de los proyectos y por último un contador de cuántas personas trabajan en ese departamento con ese proyecto y mostrar el empleado que más horas ha participado en el proyecto.

***Mi código:*** empresa2_1.sql

```
USE empresa;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dpto $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dpto()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
 
    DECLARE c1_nombreDpto VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE c1_coddpto INT;
    DECLARE c1_dniSup VARCHAR(9);
 
    DECLARE c2_nombreProy VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE c2_numProy INT;
 
    DECLARE c3_nombre VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE c3_ap1 VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE c3_dni VARCHAR(9);

    DECLARE AUX INT DEFAULT 0;
 
    DECLARE cur_departamentos CURSOR FOR SELECT nombre_dpto,codigo_dpto,dni_direct FROM departamentos;
 
    DECLARE cur_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT nombre_proyec,num_proyec FROM proyecto WHERE cod_dpto=c1_coddpto;
 
    DECLARE cur_empleado CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT nombre,ap1,dni FROM empleados WHERE dpto=c1_coddpto;
 
 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=true;
    OPEN cur_departamentos;
    FETCH cur_departamentos INTO c1_nombreDpto,c1_coddpto,c1_dniSup;
    WHILE fin=false DO
        SELECT c1_nombreDpto;
        OPEN cur_proyecto;
        FETCH cur_proyecto INTO c2_nombreProy,c2_numProy;
        WHILE fin=false DO
             SELECT c2_nombreProy;
            OPEN cur_empleado;
            FETCH cur_empleado INTO c3_nombre,c3_ap1,c3_dni;
            SET AUX = 0;
            WHILE fin=false DO
               
                SET AUX = AUX + 1;
                SELECT c3_nombre,c3_ap1 FROM trabaja_en WHERE c3_dni=dni_empleado AND c2_numProy=num_proyec ORDER BY horas LIMIT 1;
                FETCH cur_empleado INTO c3_nombre,c3_ap1,c3_dni;
            END WHILE;
            SELECT AUX;
            SET AUX =0;
            SET fin=false;
            CLOSE cur_empleado;
            FETCH cur_proyecto INTO c2_nombreProy,c2_numProy;
        END WHILE;
        SET fin=false;
        CLOSE cur_proyecto;
    FETCH cur_departamentos INTO c1_nombreDpto,c1_coddpto,c1_dniSup;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur_departamentos;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de realizar el contador no me cuenta correctamente los empleados de ese proyecto: me cuenta de más.

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** Resulta que el tercer cursor tenia que usar la tabla ***trabaja_en*** en lugar de empleados.

***2.*** Cojo la horas y creo una variable llamada ***maxHora*** para luego guardar el resultado

***3.*** En el ***if*** compruebo la hora del recorrido del tercer cursor y la variable ***maxHora*** la pongo por defecto a 0.

***4.*** Creo una variable contador el cual cuente el numero de empleados

```
USE empresa;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dpto $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dpto()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c1_nombreDpto VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE c1_coddpto INT;
    DECLARE c2_nombreProy VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE c2_numProy INT;
    DECLARE c3_dni VARCHAR(9);
    DECLARE c3_horas INT;
    DECLARE contandor INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE maxHora INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE dniMAX VARCHAR(9);
    DECLARE cur_departamentos CURSOR FOR SELECT nombre_dpto,codigo_dpto FROM departamentos;
    DECLARE cur_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT nombre_proyec,num_proyec FROM proyecto WHERE cod_dpto=c1_coddpto;
    DECLARE cur_empleado CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT dni_empleado,horas FROM trabaja_en WHERE c2_numProy=num_proyec;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=true;
    OPEN cur_departamentos;
    FETCH cur_departamentos INTO c1_nombreDpto,c1_coddpto;
    WHILE fin=false DO
        SELECT c1_nombreDpto;
        OPEN cur_proyecto;
        FETCH cur_proyecto INTO c2_nombreProy,c2_numProy;
        WHILE fin=false DO
            SELECT c2_nombreProy;
            OPEN cur_empleado;
            FETCH cur_empleado INTO c3_dni,c3_horas;
            WHILE fin=false DO
                SET contandor = contandor + 1;
                IF (c3_horas > maxHora) THEN
                    SET maxHora = c3_horas;
                    SET dniMAX = c3_dni;
                END IF;
                FETCH cur_empleado INTO c3_dni,c3_horas;
            END WHILE;
            SELECT contandor;
            SELECT nombre,ap1 FROM empleados WHERE dniMAX=dni LIMIT 1;
            SET contandor=0;
            SET maxHora=0;
            SET fin=false;
            CLOSE cur_empleado;
            FETCH cur_proyecto INTO c2_nombreProy,c2_numProy;
        END WHILE;
        SET fin=false;
        CLOSE cur_proyecto;
    FETCH cur_departamentos INTO c1_nombreDpto,c1_coddpto;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur_departamentos;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Llamo al ***Cursor*** con :

```
call dpto();
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/302)